# Asp.net MVC webgrid paging and sorting

Tags: webgrid

I have a webgrid in partial view and rending the partial view in Index.cshtml through controller action.

Ajax call for "Select" link which is inside webgrid is working fine. But Paging and sorting is not working fine. whenever the link is clicked it goes to the default loading page and webgrid disappears.

Please help me how to implement sorting and paging for this.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).